# Why do I get `SystemError: <built-in method __contains__ of dict object at ...> returned a result with an error set` when importing `pydrake` stuff?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, drake

FTR: This is my "public archival" of a Drake Slack conversation.

---

[gizatt](https://app.slack.com/team/U0K9GD333) [Sep 17th, 2019 at 2:44 PM](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568745853008800)

```
(py36_pyro) gizatt@ProblemChild:~$ python
Python 3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 30 2019, 19:07:31)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pydrake
>>> import pydrake.geometry
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pybind11::error_already_set'
what():  SystemError: <built-in method __contains__ of dict object at 0x7f266bd23438> returned a result with an error set
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any ideas where to start on this one? It only happens when importing `pydrake.geometry` , I can import `pydrake` , `pydrake.common` , `pydrake.multibody` , etc first and those work OK. Python 3.6 / Ubuntu 18.04 / current master

15 replies

[eric.cousineau](https://app.slack.com/team/U4PJQLBGR) [7 months ago](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568749249008900?thread_ts=1568745853.008800&cid=C3YB3EV5W)

> `Python 3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 30 2019, 19:07:31)`

I think the `Anaconda` part may be suspect?
(see the warning at the top here: https://drake.mit.edu/python_bindings.html

[eric.cousineau](https://app.slack.com/team/U4PJQLBGR) [7 months ago](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568749252009100?thread_ts=1568745853.008800&cid=C3YB3EV5W)
Did it work before?

[eric.cousineau](https://app.slack.com/team/U4PJQLBGR) [7 months ago](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568749266009300?thread_ts=1568745853.008800&cid=C3YB3EV5W)
And can you try running it via `/usr/bin/python3` , not Anaconda?

[gizatt](https://app.slack.com/team/U0K9GD333) [7 months ago](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568749733009500?thread_ts=1568745853.008800&cid=C3YB3EV5W)
I've been stably using it through conda for a while, this is new

[eric.cousineau](https://app.slack.com/team/U4PJQLBGR) [7 months ago](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568749772009700?thread_ts=1568745853.008800&cid=C3YB3EV5W)
Hm... Do you build it with Conda itself, or do you download the pre-built?And do you know when the last time it worked was?

[eric.cousineau](https://app.slack.com/team/U4PJQLBGR) [7 months ago](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568749779009900?thread_ts=1568745853.008800&cid=C3YB3EV5W)
(more specifically, the SHA1 of master?)

[gizatt](https://app.slack.com/team/U0K9GD333) [7 months ago](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568750663010100?thread_ts=1568745853.008800&cid=C3YB3EV5W)
<s>I build it using the conda python (the same one I'm running against there), though without the conda environment sourced -- that was working OK for a while.</s> It wasn't an upgrade of drake that broke it -- I'm suspecting some configuration tweak on my side revealed something. It broke when I was on a Drake... a week old, maybe? I upgraded and don't know what I upgraded from  (edited)

[gizatt](https://app.slack.com/team/U0K9GD333) [7 months ago](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568750722010300?thread_ts=1568745853.008800&cid=C3YB3EV5W)
No sorry it's built with `/usr/bin/python3.6` with no conda envs sourced. I then source a conda env and import drake and use it with the conda python, and that was great till now

[eric.cousineau](https://app.slack.com/team/U4PJQLBGR) [7 months ago](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568752167010600?thread_ts=1568745853.008800&cid=C3YB3EV5W)
Huh... Not sure how to help here... Are you using `conda` in a way that is `pip` compatible? Can you just do pure `virtualenv` , and avoid conda altogether? (we're using `pyro` and other stuff from `pip` , and it works just fine.) (edited)

[eric.cousineau](https://app.slack.com/team/U4PJQLBGR) [7 months ago](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568752256010900?thread_ts=1568745853.008800&cid=C3YB3EV5W)
Also, perhaps it's a difference between `python3 --version` on Ubuntu (3.6.8 on my machine) and Conda (3.6.9 on your machine)? (edited)

[gizatt](https://app.slack.com/team/U0K9GD333) [7 months ago](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568753097011200?thread_ts=1568745853.008800&cid=C3YB3EV5W)
I did a downgrade of the version in conda, versions are at least aligned now

[gizatt](https://app.slack.com/team/U0K9GD333) [7 months ago](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568753193011400?thread_ts=1568745853.008800&cid=C3YB3EV5W)
I moved a couple things at once so I'm not sure of the culprit yet, but I have identified that if I try to import `pydrake.geometry` with either of my python3.6 versions **from my home directory** , I get the problem, but if I do it from anywhere else, it's fine.  (edited)

[gizatt](https://app.slack.com/team/U0K9GD333) [7 months ago](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568753272011700?thread_ts=1568745853.008800&cid=C3YB3EV5W)
I'll just uh... chalk this up to some import path bs and call this resolved?

[eric.cousineau](https://app.slack.com/team/U4PJQLBGR) [7 months ago](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568756619011900?thread_ts=1568745853.008800&cid=C3YB3EV5W)
SGTM!Though perhaps that sounds like a magical path shadowing issue, like there's a `pydrake` folder in your home dir? (edited)

[eric.cousineau](https://app.slack.com/team/U4PJQLBGR) [7 months ago](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C3YB3EV5W/p1568756721012300?thread_ts=1568745853.008800&cid=C3YB3EV5W)
(Also, some packages subscribe to the evil of installing `*.pth` files from `setup.py` or whatevs which fiddles with `sys.path` ... so maybe that kludges things depending on where the interpreter starts?)

Answer (score 0):

The immediate fix here was to downgrade Conda's Python version to match that of `pydrake`s compiled version, and ensure no other interpreter's were getting sourced.

At present (2020/04/25), `pydrake` is not officially compiled nor tested-with `conda` / `anaconda`, so there may be unknown issues. We (Drake Developers) recommend against using it if possible, but if you do, at present you will do so at your own risk.